# Unique records with any increase per day

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp, postgis

I am new to psql.  I have a table of car ids  - `id` and their battery level - `battery` at every ten-minute interval for 2 weeks.

My goal is to create an output of the total count of unique car ids whose batteries experienced **any gain** per day.  That could mean that at any time over the course of the day where a car's battery level was higher than the previous time stamp. In other words, where the value of `battery` - the previous value of `battery` is positive.  Records with NA values under `battery` should be skipped.

I have started with the query but I am unsure how to only select unique id's whose battery levels rose.  Any recommendations would be appreciated!

```
SELECT count(distinct id), TO_CHAR(date_trunc('day', (time::timestamp) AT TIME ZONE 'EST'), 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS day FROM test_db .... 
GROUP by day 
ORDER by day
```

Here is a sample of the data :

```
  id|                           time| battery
 54 | 2017-12-12 09:50:04.402775+00 |     100
 54 | 2017-12-12 09:40:04.618926+00 |     100
 54 | 2017-12-12 09:30:04.11399+00  |     100
 54 | 2017-12-12 09:20:03.906716+00 |     100
 54 | 2017-12-12 09:10:03.955133+00 |     100
 54 | 2017-12-12 09:00:04.678508+00 |     100
 54 | 2017-12-12 08:50:03.733471+00 |     100
 54 | 2017-12-12 08:40:03.65688+00  |     100
 54 | 2017-12-12 08:30:04.260608+00 |     100
 54 | 2017-12-12 08:20:03.98387+00  |     100
 54 | 2017-12-12 08:10:04.164129+00 |      98
 54 | 2017-12-12 08:00:04.597976+00 |      98
 54 | 2017-12-12 07:50:04.501231+00 |      98
 54 | 2017-12-12 07:40:04.441531+00 |      98
 54 | 2017-12-12 07:30:04.310876+00 |      98
 54 | 2017-12-12 07:20:04.317241+00 |      98
 54 | 2017-12-12 07:10:03.856432+00 |      67
 54 | 2017-12-12 07:00:03.628862+00 |      67
 54 | 2017-12-12 06:50:03.868495+00 |      67
 54 | 2017-12-12 06:40:04.490324+00 |      67
 54 | 2017-12-12 06:30:03.83739+00  |      67
 54 | 2017-12-12 06:20:03.817014+00 |      67
 54 | 2017-12-12 06:10:04.081174+00 |      29
 54 | 2017-12-12 06:00:04.178765+00 |      29





    data_type         
--------------------------
 integer
 timestamp with time zone
 integer
```

Comment: It is unclear how the data for a given car is determined.

Comment: I have updated the table above to include data from one car on a day when the battery level goes up (as opposed to down).  The data is collected every 10 minutes from an API.   When there is no battery level reported, an NA appears.

Comment: is this enough information to solve the problem?  again, I only need to count the number of unique ids whose batteries went up during the day, not down.    Basically, if later timestamp - earlier timestamp is positive , the car should be counted

Comment: @GordonLinoff does this answer your question?